# How to make the Guess Game start again. While loop Java

Tags: java

I'm practicing Java and i tried to make a guess game but i want the game to ask for input again when the user don't guess the number right. When i guess the number wrong the loop just continuous to guess numbers until the number is the right one and the game ends.

```
import java.util.*;
class GuessGame {



private Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public GuessGame(){
    System.out.println("~~~Guess Game~~~");
    System.out.println("~~~Guess a number between 0 and 9~~~");
}

int guessedNumber = 0;

public void gameStart(){

    System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
    boolean guessedRight = false;
    boolean gameOn = true;
    int userNumber = userInput.nextInt();
    while(gameOn){
        guessedNumber = userNumber;
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        if(randomNumber == guessedNumber){
            guessedRight = true;
        }
        if(guessedRight){
            System.out.println("You guessed " + guessedNumber);
            System.out.println("The number is " + randomNumber);
            System.out.println("You won!!!");
            System.out.println("Game Over!!!");
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("You guessed " + guessedNumber);
            System.out.println("The number is " + randomNumber);
            System.out.println("Try again!!!");

        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int userNumber = userInput.nextInt();` line is responsible for getting the number that the user entered from the input line. Moving this line inside the `while` loop will ask for a number each time the loop is ran (which is only once if the user guesses right the first time).

Comment: Remember to indicate this answer as correct if it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method from a loop:

```
public GuessGame(){
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("~~~Guess Game~~~");
        System.out.println("~~~Guess a number between 0 and 9~~~");
        gameStart();
    }
}
```

This will simply restart the game as soon as the `gameStart()` method exists. (Which is when the user has guessed the right number)

Comment: @kushtrimh only wants the code to loop if the user enters the wrong value (so, keep asking until the number is correct, then exit).